# How to prevent CDK from creating default base path mapping for new DomainName

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, custom-domain, base-path

When you create a CustomDomain while creating a RestApi OR you .addDomainName after creating the RestApi in CDK, a default base path mapping is created for the specified stage to the root of the domain.

I don't want that to be created.  I want to create my own base path mapping. When I add one via domain.addBasePathMapping(), I end up with both a mapping to the root and a mapping to the specified base path. Like so:

- api: example.com / stage: dev / path: (none)         // don't want this
  one.
- api: example.com / stage: dev / path: the-base-path  //want this
  one.

Is there a way to either change the default base path mapping OR prevent it from being created?

Code reproduces the issue:

```
const apiSpec = <openapi spec loaded here>
const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'theZone', {
    domainName: 'example.com'
  });
  //Get the existing certificate
  const acmCertificate = acm.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'Certificate', CERTIFICATE_ARN);

  const apiDomainName = 'example.com';
  const theApi = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, `the-example-api`, {
    deploy: true,
    restApiName: 'ApiNameHere',
    deployOptions: {
       stageName: 'dev',
    },
    endpointTypes: [ apigateway.EndpointType.REGIONAL ],
    apiDefinition: apigateway.ApiDefinition.fromInline(apiSpec),
    endpointExportName: `endpointExportName`,
    domainName: {
      domainName: apiDomainName,
      certificate: acmCertificate,
      securityPolicy: apigateway.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2
    }
  });
  const domain = theApi.domainName
  domain.addBasePathMapping(theApi, {basePath: 'the-base-path', stage: theApi.deploymentStage});

  //Create alias record to route to apis
  const aRecord = new route53.ARecord(this, 'alias-record', {
    recordName: apiDomainName,
    zone, 
    target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.ApiGateway(theApi))
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addDomainName` method on `BaseRestApi` always uses the restApi object as the mapping parameter as seen here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/b3a7d5ba67bec09e422c0c843d7dee4653fe9aec/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/lib/restapi.ts#L346-L355

If you don't want that, don't provide the `domainName` parameter when creating the api and instead create it separate like this:

```
const domain = new apigateway.DomainName(theApi, 'CustomDomain', {
    domainName: apiDomainName,
    certificate: acmCertificate,
    securityPolicy: apigateway.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2
});
domain.addBasePathMapping(theApi, {basePath: 'the-base-path', stage: theApi.deploymentStage});
```

Comment: Finally got back to this.  I have tried this before, and unfortunately this always results in a build issue :  "Error: API does not define a default domain name."
I have been unable to get around that.  It appears that it is required to provide a "domainName" value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug that someone had reported in this github [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9581). It has since been [fixed](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/17915). Now, when you create an api, you can add `basePath` as an option to the DomainNameOptions, preventing it from creating two separate mappings. E.g.

```
  const theApi = new apigateway.SpecRestApi(this, `the-example-api`, {
    ...
    ...
    domainName: {
      domainName: apiDomainName,
      certificate: acmCertificate,
      securityPolicy: apigateway.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2,
      basePath: 'the-base-path'
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I will try to get back and update this.